# "cannot find symbol" issue with Constructor

Tags: java, constructor, symbols

Purpose of these two files:
the Object 'na' (in the first file) calls functions through the second file to analyze numbers from a text file and return the highest number, lowest number, total, and average. I am constantly getting the error "cannot find symbol"

File 1:

```
import java.io.*;    // Needed for IOException

/**
   This program demonstrates a solution to the
   Number Analysis Class programming challenge.
*/

public class NumberAnalyzerDemo
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
      // Create a NumberAnalyzer object.
      NumberAnalyzer na = new NumberAnalyzer("Numbers.txt");

      // Display data about the numbers in the file.
      System.out.println("The lowest number in the file is " +
                         na.getLowest());
      System.out.println("The highest number in the file is " +
                         na.getHighest());
      System.out.println("The total of the numbers in the file is " +
                         na.getTotal());
      System.out.println("The average of the numbers in the file is " +
                         na.getAverage());
   }
}
```

File 2:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class NumberAnalyzer
{           
    public NumberAnalyzer(String fileName)throws IOException
    {
        int count = 0;
        double total, lowest, highest, average;
        File f = new File("Numbers.txt");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
        double[] numbers = new double[11];
    }

    public void getNumbers(String fileName)
    {   
        while(s.hasNextLine())
        {
            numbers[count] = s.nextDouble();
            count++;
        }
    }

    public int getNumberOfValues(String fileName)
    {
        return count;
    }

    public double getLowest()
    {
        double lowest = numbers[0]; // set the first number in array as tester

        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            if(numbers[i] < lowest)
            {
                lowest = numbers[i];
            }
        }
        return lowest;
    }

    public double getHighest()
    {
        double highest = numbers[0]; // set the first number in array as tester

        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            if(numbers[i] > highest)
            {
                highest = numbers[i];
            }
        }
        return highest;
    }

    public double getTotal()
    {   
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            double total += numbers[i];
        }

        return total;
    }

    public double getAverage()
    {       
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            double total += numbers[i];
        }

        double average = (total / count);
        return average;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: I get 25 errors like "java: cannot find symbol" total or count or anything. They are all the same type of error

Comment: `int count = 0;` is defined a local variable in the constructor. You need to declare it as a field. Your other errors are probably similar. Read the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class NumberAnalyzer
{           
    File f;
    Scanner s;
    List<Double> numbers;

    public NumberAnalyzer(String fileName) throws IOException
    {
        f = new File("Numbers.txt");
        s = new Scanner(f);
        numbers = new ArrayList<Double>();
    }

    public void getNumbers(String fileName) throws Exception
    {   
        while(s.hasNextLine())
        {
            numbers.add(s.nextDouble());
        }

      if (numbers.size() < 1) {
        throw new Exception("Empty file or wrong path exception");
      }
    }

    public int getNumberOfValues(String fileName)
    {
        return numbers.size();
    }

    public Double getLowest()
    {
        Double lowest = numbers.get(0); // set the first number in array as tester

        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
        {
            if(numbers.get(i) < lowest)
            {
                lowest = numbers.get(i);
            }
        }
        return lowest;
    }

    public Double getHighest()
    {
        Double highest = numbers.get(0); // set the first number in array as tester

        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
        {
            if(numbers.get(i) > highest)
            {
                highest = numbers.get(i);
            }
        }
        return highest;
    }

    public Double getTotal()
    {   
        Double total = 0d;

        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
        {
            total += numbers.get(i);
        }

        return total;
    }

    public Double getAverage()
    {       
        Double total = 0d;
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
        {
            total += numbers.get(i);
        }

        Double average = (total / numbers.size());
        return average;
    }
}
```

You are declaring variables in scope of the constructor not in the class so in the methods can't access those.

Comment: You should not initialize the fields twice. And most of those fields shouldn't be fields in the first place. In particular, the Scanner, which should be created **and closed** in the only method using it.

Comment: True that, and you should probably initialize the doubles with appropriate values for this to work.

Comment: I tried the code and it compiles fine with no errors, except when I run the first file- it's saying "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at NumberAnalyzer.getLowest(NumberAnalyzer.java:43) at NumberAnalyzerDemo.main(NumberAnalyzerDemo.java:17)

Comment: I am guessing that you have no numbers in your array (some problem with the file loading or some such) and the numbers[0] contains a null value.

Comment: I modified the code a bit to help you with your errors. I used a list to make it a bit more dynamic.